# Ubuntu Mirror Monitor Resolution

Tags: ubuntu, display

right now I'm hooking up my laptop to an external monitor, and basiclly i want to mirror the view for both my laptop and my monitor. However, when I do this option, it does not let me change the resolution of the monitor, and I was wondering if there is anyway I can change this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're mirroring displays, the two monitors are displaying the exact same thing. Therefore, they can't display the exact same thing in two resolutions.

Sorry.